# How can I fix the ORA-01841 error when running a SQL query with null values in end_date in a Springboot Java application using OracleDB?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, date

I have an Oracle DB Table called Details. It has columns end_date and status.
Status Could be Active, Expired etc
end_date are dates in format `YYYY-MM-DD+HH24:MI` in varchar datatype.

In a Springboot Java application I need to define a method `findAllByFnlColltnDtBeforeNow()` in my `DetailsRepository` Interface which extends `CrudRepository`

`findAllByFnlColltnDtBeforeNow()` need to find all records which have

1. status= ACTIVE,
2. end_date is not null and
3. end_date < Sysdate

The query is

```
@Query(value ="SELECT * FROM DETAILS WHERE UPPER(status)='ACTIVE' AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD+HH24:MI')) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1",nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> findAllByFnlColltnDtBeforeNow();
```

The given query works directly in SQLDevloper (OracleDB ), but gives following error when written in Springboot Application

```
 SQL Error: 1841, SQLState: 22008
 ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

This issue occured as soon as i introduced null value in end_date. The query worked directly in SQLDevloper.

I tried using condition "and end_date is not null" but it still shows same issue

Why is the given Query working in SQLDevloper, but throwing error when calling findAllByFnlColltnDtBeforeNow() method? Also How to resolve this?